# If strings are immutable, then how is this possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

I am new to python and was going through the python3 docs. In python strings are said to be immutable, then how is this possible:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        l = 'string'
        print(l)
        l = l[:2]
        print(l)
```

returns this output:

```
string
st
```

Comment: The string itself is immutable.  The label can change.  'string' didn't stop being string.  You told l to point to a new string 'st' instead of 'string'.  l[:2] didn't cut up 'string' it just pulled out 'st' from 'string' and then you assigned that to l

Comment: Look into slices and views in Python

Answer (score 3):

Informally, `l` now points to a new immutable string, which is a copy of a part of the old one.

What you cannot do is modify a string in place.

```
a = "hello"
a[0] = "b"  # not allowed to modify the string `a` is referencing; raises TypeError

print(a)  # not reached, since we got an exception at the previous line
```

but you can do this:

```
a = "hello"
a = "b" + a[1:]  # ok, since we're making a new copy

print(a)  # prints "bello"
```

Comment: "copy of a part" what does that mean?

Comment: @coderunner007 in your example, you copied the first part of the string; the first two characters to be more precise.

Comment: i think i understood the copy part. when a string is sliced a copy of the string is made, right?

Comment: @coderunner007 as far as the programmer is concerned, yes. The original string might be reused to save memory and avoid copying, since it's immutable, but that is invisible to the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding this problem is to realize that the variable in Python is just a "pointer" pointing to an underlying object. And you confused the concept of immutable object and immutable variable(which does not exist in Python).

For instance, in your case, `l` was initially a pointer pointing to a `str` object with content "string". But later, you "redirect" it to a new `str` object whose content is "st". Note that when the program runs to the line `l = l[:2]`, it's the pointer being modified, not the object pointed to by the pointer. If you wish, you can also "redirect" `l` to another object with type other than `str`, say `l = 123`. Just remember, the original object pointed to by `l`(`str` "string") is not modified at all, it's still there in the memory (before it is garbage-collected), but just no longer pointed to by `l`.

For you to better understand the concept of immutable object, let's look at a mutable object. For example, `list` in Python is mutable.

```
l = [1, 2, 3] # a new list with three elements
l.append(4) # append a new element 4 to the list (l is now modified!!!)
```

In the code above, we modified `l` by appending a new element to it. Throughout the program, `l` points to the same object, but it's the object pointed to by `l` that is changed in the process.

Comment: If you dont mind, can you explain "strings are immutable" with respect to pointers.

Comment: Sure, I have edited my answer, but maybe it takes some minutes for you to understand. The reason why you thought that a `str` object is changed is that you mistaked "re-assignment" as "modify", while immutable means "cannot be modified". It's like when you think an engineer is not fit for your team, you have two choices: 1. send him to training, 2. replace him with another programmer. The first case is "modify", while the second is "re-assignment".

Comment: Thank you! I might have to be reassigned:))

Answer (score 0):

Strings themselves are immutable, but the variables can be bound to anything.
The id() method checks the "id" of an object. See below.

```
>>> l = 'string'
>>> print(l, id(l))
string 2257903593544
>>> l = l[:2]
>>> print(l, id(l))
st 2257912916040
```

l was bounded to a new immutable object which only contains "st".